# How is canonicity of derivative works determined for Spaceballs?

Tags: canon, spaceballs

The movie Spaceballs has spawned several pieces of spin-off media including its own animated TV series, an "official" poster-book and a novelisation of the film.

Has there ever been an official word on what canon levels exist within the Spaceballs 'verse?

Comment: I don't think anyone has ever put this much though into *Spaceballs* before today.

Comment: We have a movie event coming up. I thought I'd set the stage a little

Comment: I suspect that, at some point, Mel Brooks will make an in-universe joke about levels of canon, but otherwise, I have no input.

Comment: Spaceballs: the cannon. Indubitably.

Comment: @Buzz - Please don't "correct" people's words into American English. It's rude